# Old IBM ThinkPad laptop - only one memory slot seems to work

Tags: windows, memory

An old laptop I bought (IBM ThinkPad T30) has two memory slots but only one seems to work. When I run a memory test it seems to suggest nothing is wrong. If I put a memory module in the other slot on its own it won't work and the system beeps.

The first slot works perfectly yet I have both slots filled with 512MB and the maximum load is 1024MB.

Comment: You'll probably get more help on http://superuser.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the motherboard is defective.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested both SODIMMs in both slots?  Are both chips identical?

Have you used the IBM diagnostic or something else?

Any sign of damage on the socket?